# How references to objects work in polymorphism?

Tags: java, reference, polymorphism

```
class Animals {

.......
public void fly () {}

.....
}

class Unicorn extends animals {


public void fly() { // do something different }

public void walk() { }

}

public void doSomething (Animals p) {
    p.walk(); //errors
    p.fly(); //works depending on the class
}

public static void main()
{
    Unicorn a = new Unicorn();
    doSomething(a); //will not call walk()

}
```

As far as I know, if we pass an instance of type unicorn into doSomething, even though fly method inside the unicorn has been override,  p.fly will still call the modified version, however, it does not know walk method, why it happens, because it seems like the compiler knows how to differentiate the 2, ethos,  but doesn't know what methods are in the unicorn class? And, if p holds the reference to the instance of type unicorn, shouldn't it KNOW the instance? Because it refers  or points to the instance, isn't,  but why isn't the case???

Comment: This is quite unclear.  Please add some code to illustrate the method calls you're talking about.

Comment: `if (rand() % 2 == 0) { doSomething(new Unicorn()); } else { doSomething(new Animal()); }`.

Comment: because using polymorphism, we can just do this doSomething(Animals p) instead of doSomething(Unicorns p), but the first one can only call methods that both class have in common without casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) works in the first way you mentioned but it has nothing to do with your other example.

An `Animal` instance is able to respond to method `fly()`, then if the instance is an `Unicorn` (which is an `Animal`), the more specified version of the method will be called (and this is polymorphism).

But an `Animal` is not an `Unicorn`, so `walk()` doesn't belong to `Animal` class, the subtyping relation is not symmetric. In a situation like:

```
void method(Animal animal) {
  animal.walk();
}

method(new Unicorn());
```

You receive a compilation error because the signature of `method` accepts an `Animal`. Inside that method, the variable animal (even if at runtime is an `Unicorn`) at compile time is just known to be an `Animal`, which doesn't have method `walk()`. So the additional information on the type is discarded inside that method.

Java has a static strong type checker, which means that every verification is made at compile time. A different programming language could allow you to do what you want and throw a runtime error if you pass something which is not able to answer to `walk` method.

Comment: but Animals a = new Unicorns(); is eligible isn't it? because a holds the reference to the instance, it is like an address to the instance isn't it? why it doesnt know what inside the instance?

Comment: Because the type of the variable is given by the declaration, not by the initialization, and this is done at compile time. `Animal a = new Unicorn()` means that `a` is of type `Animal` for the type checker. And even `Unicorn u = new Unicorn(); method(u)` would upcast the `Unicorn` to `Animal` since the signature specifies `Animal`

Comment: so technically a doesn't hold a reference to new Unicorn? because it doesn't seem like a reference, it has been truncated instead of getting what inside the box

Comment: @Joshua They are two separate concepts. The *type of the expression* (which limits the methods that can be used, etc) and the type of the actual object (which is always the type following the `new`).